# Is it possible to create an index on a multi nested field on cosmos mongo db?

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Suppose I have a document Class, inside which I have an object Student, inside which I have an object say Name, within which I have a field called name. Can I create an index on that name field inside Azure Cosmos MongoDB? If so what would be the command? p.s - I am a beginner in mongoDB and Cosmos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating the container, you can check the option to create index on all the fields as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

However, if this is not checked and you still want to create indexes on nested properties you can use below command:

```
db.collection.createIndex({"Student.Name.name": 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

Cosmos indexes all paths in a document automatically by default without need to define any index explicitly. This is explained here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-overview

So, just create the item and the indexing should be taken care of.